# Eclipse RCP with project dependency

Tags: java, classpath, eclipse-rcp

I have developed an RCP plug-in (not standalone), and a Java Project with library code that the plug-in needs to call.

I have configured the Java Project in the same workspace. The plug-in has a project dependency on the Java Project.

The code compiles (the plug-in does some stuff with the Java Project / library code).

When I run the plug-in, I get a ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycode.ArgSet
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:494)
```

Anyone know how to configure the plug-in properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your library project to a plug-in project (right-click -> *Configure* -> *Convert to Plug-in Project*) and add it to the dependencies of your plug-in project (manifest editor, *Dependencies* tab).

Comment: thanks again Fabian! Do you know the reason for this? Is it to support versioning and so on?

Comment: Yes, support for different versions of a bundle is one reason that every bundle has its own class loader. You can find details about these things here: http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/

Comment: Does the new plug-in project need a Product Configuration as well? Im getting java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a JAR of your libray Project and add this jar to your plugin-project. That's the way we do it (but thats not that automatically, you have to export manualy every time you change the library-project.

The other bad with this jar-export is: when using another libraries (i.E. AXIS2 for Webservice,...) this Libraries must have also been added to the plugin project.