# How to create new Eclipse RCP project using Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse

How to create new Eclipse RCP project using Maven ([preferably m2eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html))?

I read that there's plug-in for Maven that have idea about Eclipse.
([Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)) And then it looks like I need to find some Maven Archetype to create Eclipse RCP project, but I could not. At this point I am in doubt if I go right way.

I just want to use maven dependencies resolution and other features in my RCP application development.

P.S. I found that it is possible to "Enable Dependency Management" via m2eclipse.
The other option is to make 2 project: maven project and Eclipse RCP project that will reference the first on classpath. What is the smart way?

P.P.S There's also option to use Eclipse dependency resolution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185339/eclipse-rcp-with-project-dependency)

> Convert your library project to a
>   plug-in project (right-click ->
>   Configure -> Convert to Plug-in
>   Project) and add it to the
>   dependencies of your plug-in project
>   (manifest editor, Dependencies tab).

Comment: old article Building Eclipse Plugins with Maven 2
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Eclipse-and-Maven2/index.html

Comment: Relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394475/eclipse-rcp-all-possibilities-to-define-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Tycho (http://tycho.sonatype.org/) will help you. Currently, it seems to be a little bit alpha, but after releasing Maven 3.0, Jason van Zyl promised to spend more time on Tycho (http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/10/maven-3-0-has-landed/).

Comment: As of May 2013 Tycho is slowly gaining popularity.

Answer (score 3):

Pending all the maven3 magic highlighted in [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279452/steve)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4030386/6309), you do have this [Maven RCP build recipe](http://aspsp.blogspot.com/2008/02/maven-eclipse-rcp-product-build-at-last.html), based on the [`pde-maven-plugin`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/pde-maven-plugin) (as presented in the [Eclipse Plugin Development Environment support](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/pde.html) page)

Comment: pde-maven-plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/pde-maven-plugin/ haven't bee updated for 5-6 years now.

Comment: The links are broken

Comment: @JalalSordo Thank you. I have restored/updated those links.