# Eclipse RCP - all possibilities to define dependencies?

Tags: java, dependencies, eclipse-rcp, tycho, summary

Is there somewhere a list of all possibilities, to define dependencies in an Eclipse RCP project? maybe filtered by resources?

Possible dependencies:

- from other Eclipse RCP Plugins
- by package, without explicitely defining the plugin
- jar libs
- ...

Comment: Am not sure what you mean with filtering by resources? Can you please elaborate a little more on that.

Comment: I am not sure Skip is active user. I started bounty in hope to get detailed answer about dependencies in an Eclipse RCP in general.

Comment: Good links are wanted.

Comment: Hey Paul, I am now a little bit more expirienced with RCP - today, if I find some time - I will write down in detail what I found out about dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

as you said, you can use the following directives in the `MANIFEST.MF` to define dependencies

- `Require-Bundle` (for depending on specified bundles)
- `Import-Package` (for depending on packages available by export from other bundles)
- `Bundle-Classpath` (for embedded paths(!) and JARs)

also, when you create a `Fragment`, it must define its `Fragment-Host`, of course, and that is also a dependency in a sense

in an RCP project you can setup **Features**, and you can specify dependencies to bundles for your RCP app in these features

Comment: Is MANIFEST.MF the only place to define dependencies, even with Tycho?

Comment: @PaulV with Tycho you also have the option to use POMs dependencies section when using tychos <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies> but I had mixed experiences with that approach - as far as I know, it's best to rely on MANIFEST.MF and target definition when using tycho

Comment: @PaulV some helpful links: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html http://www.vogella.com/tutorials.html http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/MavenTychoEclipsePDEToolchain https://github.com/jglander/tycho-extras/tree/p2_extras_plugin/review-1/tycho-p2-extras-plugin/src/test/resources/testProject https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin https://docs.sonatype.org/display/TYCHO/How+to+make+existing+OSGi+bundles+consumable+by+Tycho

Comment: @PaulV some more links: http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/08/26/building-an-eclipse-project-with-tycho-experience-report/ http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card

Comment: @Joerg Thank you so much. Why you just don't update you answer, it will be more readable.