# Maven archetype for Eclipse RCP

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho, maven-archetype

Is there [maven archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) (template) for Eclipse RCP / plugin ?

That is, I want something like `mvn eclipse-rcp create` (run from comand line) to get Eclipse RCP project.

See also http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/

Related [How to create new Eclipse RCP project using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029869/how-to-create-new-eclipse-rcp-project-using-maven)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using Maven Tycho to build the RCP application. It is a matured project which is utilized by the Eclipse Foundation as part of its own build infrastructure.

You can take a look at the following sample for cross platform Eclipse RCP Application building using Maven/Tycho-

https://github.com/eclipse/tycho-demo/tree/master/itp04-rcp

**UPDATE -**

There is a maven archetype for Eclipse Tycho plugin/feature build but it does not support RCP specifically.

You can take a look at it here -

https://github.com/open-archetypes/tycho-eclipse-plugin-archetype

It will build your project structure as follows -

```
__artifactId__    : parent pom project
 |
 |---__artifactId__.core   : eclipse-plugin 
 |
 |---__artifactId__.feature: eclipse-feature 
 |
 |---__artifactId__.test   : eclipse-test-plugin (Fragment project)
 |
 |---__artifactId__.site : eclipse-repository
```

This leaves out building the RCP app. For that you will have to add a pom.xml file where your .product file lies. Tycho will pick up settings from this .product file.

At the very lease your pom.xml must have the following -

https://github.com/eclipse/tycho-demo/blob/master/itp04-rcp/eclipse-repository/pom.xml

Comment: Hi Pushkar. Thanks. When developing Eclipse RCP wit Maven, we are sure to use Tycho. You haven't answered questions: Is there Maven archetype?